KDE - Update installed apps' icons based on category
I wonder if on KDE (plasmashell 6.2.4) we can make all already installed apps update their icon based on their category?
Let me try to explain what I want to ask:

If I consider the calculator, screenshot and krite being in the same category (just example, will take the first category of the app in the desktop file) then you have the category icon for each and then on the bottom right the normal icon of the app.
So I wonder if it is possible. It would make it way faster for me to develop a theme for KDE for my favourite streamer ^^. Just having to make the category icons and call it a day.
Thank you for reading, have a good day.
